Getting an OperationError Error While Deploying Python App to Google Cloud Functions
I am trying to deploy a basic Python application on Google Cloud Functions through the google cloud shell.
Command That I am Executing:
  gcloud functions deploy python-http-function \
    --gen2 \
    --runtime=python312 \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --source=. \
    --entry-point=hello_http \
    --trigger-http \
    --allow-unauthenticated

Output:
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Could not create or update Cloud Run service you-called, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'you-called-00001-tiy' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=gcp-learning-417116&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/you-called/revision_name/you-called-00001-tiy&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22you-called%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22you-called-00001-tiy%22 
For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

main.py

import functions_framework

from markupsafe import escape
@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and "name" in request_json:
        name = request_json["name"]
    elif request_args and "name" in request_args:
        name = request_args["name"]
    else:
        name = "World"
    return f"Hello {escape(name)}!"

requirements.txt
functions-framework==3.*

What modification do I need to make to successfully deploy the app to the Cloud Function??

did you forget to add the @functions_framework.http decorator?
google source

not working even after adding the decorator.

where did http.route come from?
import function_framework

@functions_framework.http
def you_called(request):


like this: from functions_framework import http

the import looks ok, i mean @http <newline because i can't format here; no blank line> def you_called(request): without the .route("/")

I have used @http.route('/'), you can see that in the main.py file that I have included above.

Let me try the documentation's example.

yes.. but... why did you add .route('/') in the first place? it's not noted in the google documentation (linked again)

ok! got it, no need to use .route

but even after using the documentation's code, it is giving the same error.

did you set entrypoint and source? (scroll down in docs)

not working even after setting entrypoint and source, ran this command:
gcloud functions deploy python-http-function --gen2 --runtime=python312 --region=us-central1 --source=.  --entry-point=hello_http --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated

I have tried to deploy at my end, but I didn't face any errors. Can you redeploy once and see. Also what does the logs showing in Logs URL? Also have a look at this Link1 and Link2.

sure! will do it from scratch.

What's the log entry tell?

log entry showed these errors:
  "textPayload": "Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container \"worker\" on port 8080. The instance was not started.",
  "insertId": "660f8f1e000283eb58630686",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "configuration_name": "python-http-function",
      "revision_name": "python-http-function-00001-jox",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "service_name": "python-http-function",
      "project_id": "gcp-learning-417116"
    }
  },
  "severity": "ERROR"
}```

  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 5, in <module>
    from functions_framework._cli import _cli
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import flask
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)```

It seems like the issue is with the Markup package. Can you try to import the ‘Markup’ from ‘markupsafe’ instead of ‘jinja2’ as suggested in this Stackoverflow Link. Also the other solution to this error is downgrading the Jinja2 module to a compatible version or upgrading the flask to the latest version.
